# Getting null point in Unit test

Tags: unit-test, product

In my update I have created a product and I am referring this product to a OpportunityLineItem am getting an error

> System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object

But when I do debug I am able to view the record id Of product. Do anyone have any idea on this. Do I am missing out anything.

```
 public static testmethod void autoPopulateProjectFields(){

    Account acc = new Account();
    acc.Name = 'AccName';
    insert acc;

    Id pricebookId = Test.getStandardPricebookId();
    Product2 p2 = new Product2(Name          = 'Product X', 
                               ProductCode   = 'Pro-X', 
                               isActive      = true,
                               List_Price__c = 300);
    insert p2;

    PricebookEntry pbEntry = new PricebookEntry(Pricebook2Id = pricebookId,
                                                Product2Id   = p2.Id,
                                                UnitPrice    = 100.00,
                                                IsActive     = true);
    insert pbEntry;

    Asset ass         = new Asset();
    ass.Name          = 'siteName';
    ass.AccountId     = acc.ID;
    insert ass;           

    Opportunity opp   = new Opportunity();
    opp.Name          = 'OppName';
    opp.StageName     = 'Qualified';
    opp.CloseDate     = Date.Today().addDays(5);
    opp.DomainName__c = 'Test Domain';
    insert opp;

    OpportunityLineItem oppLine = new OpportunityLineItem();
    oppLine.Opportunity         = opp;
    System.debug('Product :::' + p2);
    System.debug('Product details :::' + p2.Id);
    System.debug('Product details :::' + [SELECT Id FROM Product2 WHERE Id = :p2.Id].Id);
    oppLine.Product2.Id         = p2.Id; // I am getting error on this line 
    //oppLine.Product2.Id         = [SELECT Id FROM Product2 WHERE Id = :p2.Id].Id;
    oppLine.Quantity            = 1;
    oppLine.UnitPrice           = 250;
    insert oppLine;

    AssetOpportunity__c assOpp  = new AssetOpportunity__c();
    assOpp.Opportunity__c       = opp.Id;  
    assOpp.Site__c              = ass.Id;
    insert assOpp;

    opp.StageName               = 'Closed Won';
    ProjectTriggerHandler.isUpdate = True;
    update opp;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed this issue with changing

```
oppLine.Product2.Id         = p2.Id;
```

To

```
oppLine.PricebookEntryId    = pbEntry.Id;
```